# Trying to display online pdf's in an android application (using kotlin) webview using google drive will occasionally produce errors

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, google-drive-api

I have been trying to fix this all day long. I am trying to display various pdf's saved online on a web view using google drive, so that it loads page by page, but doesn't download it locally.

Whenever I go into the webview to load the pdf it will usually work, but once every couple of tries I will get the following error:

```
"Uncaught CustomError: Did not receive drive#about kind when fetching import map:undefined", source: https://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-viewer/_/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.iw.nPmJUigVjYY.O/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AC2dHMJ5W67xChDpdTOaSavkSV5aN0BM8g/m=main (92)
[INFO:CONSOLE(92)] "Uncaught [object Object]", source: https://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-viewer/_/js/k=apps-viewer.standalone.iw.nPmJUigVjYY.O/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AC2dHMJ5W67xChDpdTOaSavkSV5aN0BM8g/m=main (92)
```

I have been trying to find out what is causing this all day long but have not managed to fix it. Any Ideas what might be causing it/how I can fix it?

I am coding this app using kotlin, here is the fragment I am using to display PDF's, it gets a pdf url from a database, the url itself is not problematic.

```
class WebViewPdf : Fragment() {

lateinit var webView: WebView
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    if (pdfLoadingPanel != null) {
        pdfLoadingPanel.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    var view = inflater.inflate(com.madortilofficialapps.tilquiz.R.layout.fragment_pdf_view, container, false)
    webView = view.findViewById(
            com.madortilofficialapps.tilquiz.R.id.webView) as WebView
    var googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url="
    val url = arguments!!.getString("url")
    webView.invalidate()
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
    webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    var didLoadPDF = false
    Log.d("LKJLKHLKHLHLKHLHKLH","Starting")
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            Log.d("lkhnjlkjlkj", "Loading")
            if (pdfLoadingPanel != null) {
                pdfLoadingPanel.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            didLoadPDF = true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
           if(!didLoadPDF){
                webView.loadUrl(googleDocs + url)
            }else {
                Log.d("dagfagaga", "Finished loading")
                if (pdfLoadingPanel != null) {
                    pdfLoadingPanel.visibility = View.GONE
                }
               if(webView.title == ""){
                   webView.reload()
               }
            }
        }
    }
    webView.loadUrl(googleDocs + url)
    return view
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    webView.clearCache(true)
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    activity?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    webView.destroy()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    activity?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR)
}
```

EDIT: I managed to fix it, here is how for people with this problem in the future. Basically I debugged the webView.Title and found that whenever it gave me the error the title was not what I wanted. continuing with that I found that for some reason, even though the url variable was a val, it changed after every time, adding the googleDocs variable to the start of it, becoming something like this: "https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=example.pdf", so what I did was add the googleDocs to the URL in the start of the program, before I start the webView, then only load the URL by itself, that way even when the webView didn't load at first and tried to load again recursively the URL didn't grow.

Comment: Had the same problem. The only solution that worked for me was to try load it as many times as needed. Sometimes it takes even 10 times lol.

Comment: @xinaiz Is there a way to programmatically identify if it didn't load properly so that I can reload it through the program without having the user load it?

Comment: Since you solved it, you should post an answer with solution and accept it after 24h :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (view.getTitle().equals(""))
        view.reload();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.